# OpenMP: are variables automatically shared?

Tags: c++, openmp

We already know that local variables are automatically private.

```
int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j)
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

it is equal to

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How about the other variables ? are they shared by default or do we need to specify shared() like in the example below ?

```
bool sorted(int *a, int size)
{
  bool sorted = true;
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(a, size, sorted)
  {
#pragma omp for reduction (&:sorted)
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) sorted &= (a[i] <= a[i + 1]);
  }
  return sorted;
}
```

Can we not specify the shared and work directly with our (a, size, sorted) variables ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are shared by default in a `parallel` section unless there is a `default` clause specified. Note that this is not the case for all OpenMP directives. For example, this is generally not the case for tasks. You can read that from the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf):

> In a parallel, teams, or task generating construct, the data-sharing attributes of these variables are determined by the `default` clause, if present (see Section 5.4.1).
>
> - In a **parallel** construct, if no default clause is present, these variables are **shared**.
> - For constructs other than **task** generating constructs, if no default clause is present, these variables reference the variables with the same names that exist in the enclosing context.
> - In a **target** construct, variables that are not mapped after applying data-mapping attribute rules (see Section 5.8) are `firstprivate`.

You can safely rewrite your code as the following:

```cpp
bool sorted(int *a, int size)
{
    bool sorted = true;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(&:sorted)
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
       sorted &= a[i] <= a[i + 1];
    return sorted;
}
```